# redirecting after facebook app request

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api

I am sure it is a simple question but I am not familiar to the Facebook api. I have a Facebook app, and I send some `app request`

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
                             message: 'Would you join me ?' + ' ' + url,
                             to: $some_id
                             });
```

The app request is correctly sent but when when the invited user clicks on his Facebook space notification, he is not redirected to the `url` but instead in some `https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/....` url which crashes. It seems to be my canvas page but what am I suppose to do with this url, how do I put code to redirect the user ?

Answer (score 0):

App requests should only be used for Canvas applications - the notifications will always link to the Canvas URL for your application. You can simply point the Canvas URL to a page within your app to redirect the user elsewhere, but it's not permitted by Facebook Policies.

As the Platform Policy states:

> Don’t build an app whose primary purpose is to redirect people off of
>   Facebook.

Comment: thank you for your response. But where do I put my code for this canvas page ? btw, if I had to bypass facebook policies, where do I put the redirection code ?

Comment: Put the code on a page, and then point the Canvas URL to it. It will need to be a JavaScript redirect using: `window.top.location`.

Comment: thank you for your response. But I put correct Canvas Url in my Facebook dashboard, but when clicking on the app request, the user is redirected to `https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/...` and here the app crashes... How is it possible ?

Comment: Add a forward slash `/` to the end of the Canvas URL - point it to a folder instead of a file.

Comment: my canvas url is already correctly formatted : `http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/folder2/`